# Whitehead's problem equivalent.

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, topological-groups

A couple weeks ago I assited a talk about Whitehead´s problem and there the speaker mentioned that such statement is equivalent to the next:

($\star$) Every abelian, compact (Hausdorff off course) and path-connected topological group is isomorphic (as a topological group) to some circles product.

I have been looking on internet but I can not find neither the equivalence nor the second statement itself.

Somebody knows where can I read about this and if there is some proof of ($\star$)'s consistency (and independence) that does not go trough Whitehead´s problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I presume that the circles product is somehow the free-ness, and the connectedness is somehow having a trivial Ext.

Comment: You can find a footnote about this in Rotman's book, on page 436 where it says that Diximer proved this fact, but no reference is given.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila . Is that Diximer or Dixmier? (I had a book on $C^*$ algebras by someone named Dixmier.:)

Comment: @user254665: You're right, it's Dixmier.

Comment: The topological group must be abelian.

Comment: I mentioned this fact in my talk because a friend of mine who works in harmonic analysis had told me about it. The only reference I found was this one: http://bit.ly/2fKMNYv

Comment: Camilo! How are you? Thank you very much!